# Update a property from a string to object on JavaScript without mutation

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutability

When iterating through an object and updating it I feel that I am not doing it right. This is the method I have built to do it and I have doubts about `record[header] = {label: record[header]};`

Does anybody have a better solution to avoid mutation **records** array?

```
setAfterRecords(preview: any): void {
    const { columns: headers } = preview;
    const { rows: records } = preview;

    records.map((record, i) => {
        headers.forEach(header => {
            record[header] = {
                label: record[header],
            };
        });

        return record;
    });

    this.after = { headers, records };
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to alter the original array, clone it and alter the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it. It uses the new-ish object spread operator (`...` on `{}`). It's like `Object.assign()` but in a more concise syntax.

```
setAfterRecords(preview: any): void {
  const { columns: headers, rows: records } = preview;

  // Build a new array of records.
  const newRecords = records.map(record => {

    // Build a new record object, adding in each header.
    return headers.reduce((c, header) => {

      // This operation shallow-copies record from the initial value or
      // previous operation, adding in the header.
      return { ...c, [header]: { label: record[header] } }
    }, record)
  })

  this.after = { headers, records: newRecords };
}
```

Comment: This works like charm @Joseph. Thank you so much, mate. :)